# Insert spring at nth column in csv file using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to insert string in front of each value separated by comma using .
for Example
input as :

```
abc,xyz,12345,NY,USA
```

expected output :

```
name=abc,id=xyz123,zip=12345,city=NY,country=USA
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , thank you for checking

```
awk -F',' '{print "name=",$1,",""id=",$2,",""zip=",$3,",""city=",$4,",""country=",$5}'
```

This adds extra space, which I cleared using sed .

Comment: FYI, a CSV can contain double quoted fields that might break your script.

Comment: Here's a more robust solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45420607/3387716